# Ports open for SSH

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

My home server is accessible via SSH, therefore I've opened port 22. If I wish to access my server from anywhere else in the world via SSH, do all the routers my laptop connects to also need port 22 open?

Comment: please rewrite your question .. I can't understand your point

Comment: Hope that helps, sorry.

Comment: Yes, now it's clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are accessing a system on your network via SSH you don't need port 22 open on every network you visit. The port is used by your router to point this specific request to the right place.

On a side note I suggest not using the default port for SSH. Makes life to easy for the scripting kiddies and bots to start poking at your security. Stick it on a nice four digit port number.

Answer (score 0):

You need every firewall between the client and the server allows traffic on port 22 **from** the client **to** the server ...

Normally university FW and public networks do **not** filter *output* traffic, so you should not have this kind of problem.

On the other hand, if you need to access your PC **behind** your router, you don't need to open the port 22 *on the router* (this way you'd be able only to login on the router itself), you have to open port 22 on the  PC *and* setup a **port Redirect on the router** .. redirecting traffic from port XX (may be 22 but you should be able to choose a port you want) to port 22 of your PC

Comment: So if I were to connect from my laptop to server, and I configured my router to be open @ port 999, then my SSH client would need to attempt connection on port 999 and the router will accordingly deal with packets it receives? This seems better [security wise], although I'm sure it doesn't protect me against port scanners used on my IP. Also, would traffic not be slower because of the redirection (and my router being a standard ISP-provided one)?

Comment: No, you need to configure **port redirect** from your router port 999 to port 22 of your server. You need redirect, not opening.

Yes .. your client will connect to port 999 of the public IP associated with the external interface of your router

Comment: Is "intended port" information in each IP header then?

Comment: @AlberT | Why does he need a redirect. Simply opening the desired port and have the server listen on that port is enough. Why do you suggest this method?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Opening a port on the router means accepting connection ON the router, not forwarding the traffic to another device (the server) .. or I totally had misunderstood the  question?

Obviously I'm taking into account the "standard" scenario in which the server has an RFC1918 IP (non public), so the only accessible IP is the one of the router itself .. if the server is already mapped on the public network the scenario is totally different (but what does the router matter in this case?)

Comment: @AlberT | This might be a terminology issue here. When I say "open a port" I mean create a port forwarding rule which points at the desired internal IP. I would never even hint at the idea of a home user allowing connections directly onto the router. From my understanding this is what the OP is discussing.

Comment: @adampski you will not notice any appreciable performance downgrade. the intended port info is only known by your router, it is not in any packet .. the router will rewrite for you the incoming header and change the destination ip for you, making the reverse for response packets (masquerading)

Comment: @MatthewWilliams yes, if you intend port forwarding we are saying the same thing then :)

Comment: @MatthewWilliams that's how my router is currently configured. I don't see the need to "trigger" any ports if this rule is functioning correctly and safely.

Comment: @adampski | If your router is configured to port forward you don't need to do anything else (except not using port 22 as suggested in my answer). You can access this from where ever you want using Putty or something. Point at your external IP and desired port to connect.

Answer (score -2):

On your router make sure the port 22 is open and set up a port forwarding rule to point to the  static IP. e.g. 192.168.0.4

Make sure you firewall on your laptop is allowing incoming and outgoing connections on port 22.

Make sure any other devices such as a switch for example is doing the same - allowing port 22 to be open and forwarding correctly.

Comment: -1 .. confusionary concepts. Sorry

- a static IP is not strictly needed, it can be fixed by DHCP for example
- a port doesn't **points** to an IP
- a switch is normally a Level 2 device, it does not act as a firewall
- outgoing connection on the server side is not pertinent, normally this is handled by related-traffic rules

Comment: I skipped a step. Should be make sure the port 22 is open and set up a port forwarding rule to point to the IP address of the laptop. Will update the answer. Depending on the setup of the modem/router it could be setup to disable all outgoing ports (then manually have to add them in). I put that there so he can check. Your keyword there is "normally".

Comment: You was talking of the firewall **on** the laptop, not the outgoing filter of the router ..

Comment: Also, unless he is using a high end switch (usually used in corporate networks) he won't need to, and probably couldn't anyway, configure anything on this device. The switch will simply receive something from the router and send a generic request to anything plugged into it and take whatever response it gets.

Comment: High end or cheap it should be a L3 switch .. which is in fact not common for home environments ;)

Comment: @AlberT | I should have said high performance Layer 3 to be precise. They are indeed not common in home environments. Most people are perfectly happy with just their router and use a switch for extra ethernet points.

Comment: I agree with you @MatthewWilliams, did not want scare ;)

Comment: Very true, you have to think of all possibilities though ;) @AlberT: I did mention the firewall too as well as the router. All aspects that could cause the problem.